# Titulo con multilinea cuando está expandido en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Me encuentro que el titulo queda cortado por puntos cuando se expande con `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

[image: Coordinator Example]

¿Alguna manera de que no se corte el titulo, pero manteniendo su tamaño?

No ser si se puede intercarlar dos vista, porque mi idea seria detectar cuando está expandido la toolbar muestre una vista con un `TextView` multi linea y cuando se colapse se oculte con transición hacia el titulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dale un vistazo a este [repo de Github](https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar) en donde hace uso de multilínea tal como lo quieres:

**Instalación**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.opacapp:multiline-collapsingtoolbar:1.2.2'
}
```

**Uso**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:maxLines="3">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]